# When hiding the tabBar on specific screen, it displays gray area at the bottom of page on Expo app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I have nested routes which I'm using expo-router. I tried to hide the tabBar for the specific page but in this case, it displays a gray area. I set the display option to none on the tabBarStyles options and also set the enabledScreens false if it's an IOS device.  This is how looks my routes:
---app---
---_layout--- (Stack.Screen)
---home---
---_layout--- (Tabs.Screen)
---contacts---
---_layout--- (Stack.Screen)

This is the tab screen inside the layout of home:

```
 <Tabs.Screen
  name="contacts"
  options={{
   href: "/home/contacts",
   title: t("Navigation.Contacts"),
   tabBarStyle: {
     display: isAddContactPath ? "none" : "flex",
   }
```

This is the root component of application:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!isAndroid) {
      enableScreens(false)
    }
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  What ended up working for me was adding `position: 'absolute'` to the `tabBarStyle`.